# ionic 2 - Error: Expected a non-empty string argument

Tags: angular, google-maps, ionic2

I wanted to display markers on the map based on the `postcode` that is stored in `JSON` format.

I am able to access the `JSON` data and display the markers based on the lat and long values that is in the `JSON` data.

When I try to use `postcode`, it fails and shows an error message of

> Expected a non-empty string argument.

While I did use `console.log` to test my `postcode`, it does retrieve the data.

I assume that the error occurs because the `postcode` value did not pass into the `forwardgeocode`.

I am running the application on my device using Xcode.

**map.ts**

```
ionViewDidLoad(){

  this.platform.ready().then(() => {

  let mapLoaded = this.maps.init(this.mapElement.nativeElement, this.pleaseConnect.nativeElement);
  let locationsLoaded = this.maps.load();

  Promise.all([
    mapLoaded,
    locationsLoaded
  ]).then((result) => {

    let locations = result[1];

    for (let location of locations) {

      let postcode = location.postcode;
      console.log(postcode); //did shown up

    this.nativeGeocoder.forwardGeocode(postcode)
    .then((coordinates: NativeGeocoderForwardResult) => {
      this.maps.addMarker(coordinates.latitude, coordinates.longitude);
    })
    .catch((error: any) => console.log(error));

    }

  });
});
```

}

**JSON DATA**

```
{
"locations": [

    {
        "title": "Location A",
        "latitude": 1.418744,
        "longitude": 103.837302,
        "postcode":768547
    },
    {
        "title": "Location B",
        "latitude": 1.418744, 
        "longitude": 103.833300,
        "postcode":760798
    },
    {
        "title": "Location C",
        "latitude": 1.417349, 
        "longitude": 103.833021,
        "postcode":769092
    }
]
}
```

**console.log(postcode)**

```
2017-07-18 01:23:49.387587+0800 MyApp[15636:8899335] 769092
2017-07-18 01:23:49.388004+0800 MyApp[15636:8899335] 760846
2017-07-18 01:23:49.388257+0800 MyApp[15636:8899335] 768448
```

Comment: why are you writing this code in the `app.component.ts`

Comment: @arkade Hi, it's not in the app.component.ts. The code was in my generated map page's typescript. Thanks for correcting my poor english.

Comment: why is there a `this.platform.ready()`? was that autogenerated? Also what is the code for `forwardGeocode()` , does it return a promise? Also what are the returned results here -> `console.log(postcode); //did shown up`

Comment: `this.platform.ready()` is used for checking the loading process of the map before trying to add the marker. `forwardGeocode` I followed the documentation. `console.log(postcode)` it did show up all the postcode in the array but when use `this.nativeGeocoder.forwardGeocode(postcode)`, it returns the error message.

Comment: I followed  [joshmorony's](http://www.joshmorony.com/create-a-nearby-places-list-with-google-maps-in-ionic-2-part-2/) tutorial and modify it.

Comment: But what is `.forwardGeocode(postcode)` . What is the code in that method?. That code is not in the tutorial. If that method is not returning a promise, or the returned data is incorrect then there is an issue. Cant really tell otherwise

Comment: It's actually from the [Ionic doc](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/native-geocoder/).  I did a test for `forwardGeocode("768448")`, it does succeed and return the result of the lat and lng. I am trying to loop the function so that it will return multiple markers on map.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your json data, `"postcode":769092` is of type `Number` not `String`.
Convert to String and try:

```
let codeToPass = postcode.toString();
this.nativeGeocoder.forwardGeocode(codeToPass);
```

[forwardGeocode Reference](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/native-geocoder/#forwardGeocode)

Comment: Thanks you guys! It works! Struggled with this for few days. Really appreciate your help.